# Possible to use `mask` or `where` in pandas on a whole dataframe but change only one columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, method-chaining

When method chaining with `pandas` dataframes, it's often necessary to mask one particular column, not a whole dataframe.

The documentation for `pandas` has `mask` or `where` for a whole [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask) or a [series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html).

Is there some way to pass `mask` to a whole dataframe, but only change one column?

As an example, say we have data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2], 'B' : [3,4,5]})
```

Now we can either do `df.mask(df > 0, 2)` and the whole dataframe will be:

```
|A | B | 
|--|---|
|0 | 2 |
|2 | 2 |
|2 | 2 |
```

Or I can do `df.A.mask(df.A >0,2)` which will give me:

```
|A|
|0|
|2|
|2|
```

Is there a way to do this?:

```py
df.mask(df.A > 0, 2) 

|A | B|
|0 | 3|
|2 | 4|
|2 | 5|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) together with mask.

```
df.mask(df['A']>0, df.assign(**{'A': 2}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace a specified column by using ``ìnplace=True``` in function. Same as for `where`.

```
df.A.mask(df.A>0, 2, inplace=True)
```

Comment: But is it possible to pass just the whole dataframe? So `df.mask(df.A>0,2)`. In your case you're passing the series which will output a series, but if you wanted to chain methods on the dataframe, it wouldn't work.

Comment: In my case, I am passing the series which will replace directly the column A of df. You can do df.head() and you'll find out that column A has been changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. What I'm looking for, though is to input a dataframe with some number of columns, and then output the dataframe with that number of columns. In your case, I input a series, and get a series back, but how can I input the whole frame, df, mask it and get the whole frame, df, back?